# Error on deallocating CCTMXTiledMap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I know that CCTMXTiledMap is an autorelease object.
I also know that CCTMXTiledMap should not be re-initialized.
But, how can I change Scene?

I got deallocating errors on TMXTiledMap object when changing scene.
Here is the properties and dealloc method of scene 1.

```
@interface MapObj : NSObject {
CCTMXTiledMap *theMap;
CCTMXLayer *bgLayer;
CCTMXLayer *terrainLayer;
NSMutableArray *virtualMap;
NSUInteger h, w;
}

 @property (nonatomic, retain) CCTMXTiledMap *theMap;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) CCTMXLayer *bgLayer;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) CCTMXLayer *terrainLayer;
 @property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableArray *virtualMap;

-(void) dealloc {

[bgLayer release];    //self.bgLayer = [theMap layerNamed:@"bg"];
self.bgLayer = nil;
[terrainLayer release];  //self.terrainLayer = [theMap layerNamed:@"pl"];
self.terrainLayer = nil;

[theMap release];  //self.theMap = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"newmaptest.tmx"];
self.theMap = nil;

[virtualMap release];   //just an array, not related to TMX
self.virtualMap = nil;
[super dealloc]; }
```

I got error at scene change (unsuccessful dealloc of scene 1)

```
- (void) dealloc
{
CCLOGINFO( @"cocos2d: deallocing %@", self);

// attributes
[camera_ release];

[grid_ release];

// children
CCNode *child;
CCARRAY_FOREACH(children_, child)
    child.parent = nil; <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<EXC_BAD_ACCESS

[children_ release];

[super dealloc];}
```

Here is the log

```
2012-11-16 16:37:10.402 VerBeta[4876:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCScene = 0024F5D0 | Tag = -1>
2012-11-16 16:37:10.405 VerBeta[4876:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCArray = 00233F80> = ( <Playground = 0022C880 | Tag = -1>, )
2012-11-16 16:37:10.408 VerBeta[4876:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCTexture2D = 002373B0 | Name = 2 | Dimensions = 128x32 | Coordinates = (0.60, 0.88)>
2012-11-16 16:37:10.412 VerBeta[4876:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCLabelTTF = 0023A220 | FontSize = 20.0>
2012-11-16 16:37:10.416 VerBeta[4876:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCTexture2D = 00230B90 | Name = 11 | Dimensions = 128x32 | Coordinates = (0.76, 0.88)>
2012-11-16 16:37:10.419 VerBeta[4876:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCLabelTTF = 00245040 | FontSize = 20.0>
2012-11-16 16:37:10.422 VerBeta[4876:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCTMXTilesetInfo: 0x249e70>
2012-11-16 16:37:10.425 VerBeta[4876:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCSprite = 0024B0B0 | Rect = (0.00,0.00,32.00,32.00) | tag = -1 | atlasIndex = 149>
2012-11-16 16:37:10.428 VerBeta[4876:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCTextureAtlas = 00249C00 | totalQuads =  150>
2012-11-16 16:37:10.433 VerBeta[4876:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCArray = 00249FB0> = ( )
2012-11-16 16:37:10.436 VerBeta[4876:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCTMXLayer = 0024ADC0 | Tag = 0>
2012-11-16 16:37:10.439 VerBeta[4876:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCArray = 00249BA0> = ( )
2012-11-16 16:37:10.442 VerBeta[4876:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCTMXTilesetInfo: 0x24a150>
2012-11-16 16:37:10.445 VerBeta[4876:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCSprite = 0024BC00 | Rect = (32.00,0.00,32.00,32.00) | tag = -1 | atlasIndex = 149>
2012-11-16 16:37:10.448 VerBeta[4876:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCTextureAtlas = 0024B560 | totalQuads =  150>
2012-11-16 16:37:10.452 VerBeta[4876:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCArray = 002494C0> = ( )
2012-11-16 16:37:10.455 VerBeta[4876:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCTMXLayer = 0024B400 | Tag = 1>
2012-11-16 16:37:10.457 VerBeta[4876:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCArray = 00248DD0> = ( )
2012-11-16 16:37:10.461 VerBeta[4876:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCTMXTiledMap = 002474A0 | Tag = -1>
```

I have tried not releasing *theMap*. Such as commenting out these two lines

```
//[theMap release];
//self.theMap = nil;
```

However error still occurs, log is here

```
2012-11-16 16:34:21.000 VerBeta[4850:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCScene = 00242580 | Tag = -1>
2012-11-16 16:34:21.003 VerBeta[4850:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCArray = 00226F30> = ( <Playground = 0021F830 | Tag = -1>, )
2012-11-16 16:34:21.007 VerBeta[4850:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCTexture2D = 00225190 | Name = 2 | Dimensions = 128x32 | Coordinates = (0.60, 0.88)>
2012-11-16 16:34:21.010 VerBeta[4850:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCLabelTTF = 0022D1D0 | FontSize = 20.0>
2012-11-16 16:34:21.014 VerBeta[4850:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCTexture2D = 0022D0A0 | Name = 3 | Dimensions = 128x32 | Coordinates = (0.76, 0.88)>
2012-11-16 16:34:21.017 VerBeta[4850:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCLabelTTF = 00237FF0 | FontSize = 20.0>
2012-11-16 16:34:21.021 VerBeta[4850:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCTMXTilesetInfo: 0x23ce20>
2012-11-16 16:34:21.024 VerBeta[4850:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCSprite = 0023E060 | Rect = (0.00,0.00,32.00,32.00) | tag = -1 | atlasIndex = 149>
2012-11-16 16:34:21.027 VerBeta[4850:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCTextureAtlas = 0023CBB0 | totalQuads =  150>
2012-11-16 16:34:21.030 VerBeta[4850:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCArray = 0023CF60> = ( )
2012-11-16 16:34:21.034 VerBeta[4850:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCTMXLayer = 0023DD70 | Tag = 0>
2012-11-16 16:34:21.038 VerBeta[4850:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCArray = 0023CB50> = ( )
2012-11-16 16:34:21.041 VerBeta[4850:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCTMXTilesetInfo: 0x23d100>
2012-11-16 16:34:21.044 VerBeta[4850:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCSprite = 0023EBB0 | Rect = (32.00,0.00,32.00,32.00) | tag = -1 | atlasIndex = 149>
2012-11-16 16:34:21.047 VerBeta[4850:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCTextureAtlas = 0023E510 | totalQuads =  150>
2012-11-16 16:34:21.050 VerBeta[4850:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCArray = 0023C470> = ( )
2012-11-16 16:34:21.053 VerBeta[4850:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCTMXLayer = 0023E3B0 | Tag = 1>
2012-11-16 16:34:21.056 VerBeta[4850:307] cocos2d: deallocing <CCArray = 0023BD80> = ( )
VerBeta(4850,0x3e29f898) malloc: *** error for object 0x23b660: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Comment: Are you using retain/strong propeties? If not, you should use them for objects. Could you please write down the property declarations?

Comment: @Dave Thank you for your help, properties added above. Yes I am using retain property. Any problem?

Comment: How do you do the @synthesize? Are you created iVar assigned to the property? If not, you should use [_bgLayer release]; in the dealloc.

Comment: @Dave I have done it straight forward. 
\@synthesize theMap;
\@synthesize bgLayer;
\@synthesize terrainLayer;
\@synthesize virtualMap; 
Am I violating the convention?

Comment: These synthesizes are good, but creates _bgLayer as object and self.bgLayer as a ponter to the object. If you call [bgLayer release]; then it will be executed on the pointer, not on the object. Please call [_bgLayer release]; etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not assigning ivar to property, you should not call `[propertyName release]`, instead use `[_propertyName release];`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the convention. I have changed the convention to _ivar for direct access/ivar for property access. But the problem not solved, error still occurs. So, maybe this is not a conventional problem?

Comment: Furthermore, I cleaned all unnecessary properties, and left theMap (since this is the TMXTiledMap which has to add to the Scene). The execution stops sharply at deallocating TMXTiledMap